# Optical reader answer sheet

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would one go about reproducing an answer sheet like this? The sheet would be generated depending on the number of question in an exam document class. Some questions (1 - 24) are multiple choice questions, while the others (25 - 35) are open questions and the part of the answer sheet that refers to those questions would be filled by the grader with numbers beside the questions on the answer sheet representing the marks the student got on that specific question.
[image]

Here is what I managed with my limited TikZ knowledge.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \tikzmath{\x=1;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1.1cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=2;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.2cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=3;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.3cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=4;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4.4cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=5;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.5cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=6;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-6.6cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=7;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-7.7cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=8;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-8.8cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=9;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-9.9cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=10;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (-2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {A};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {B};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {C};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {D};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=11;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-3.7,5.5) {Solve problems 11 - 15 in the exam paper.};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm, yshift=-1.1cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=11;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {0};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {1};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {2};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.2,5.5) {NO};
        \node at (-2.5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm, yshift=-2.2cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=12;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {0};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {1};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {2};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.2,5.5) {NO};
        \node at (-2.5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm, yshift=-3.3cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=13;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {0};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {1};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {2};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {3};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-2.2,5.5) {NO};
        \node at (-1.5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm, yshift=-4.4cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=14;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {0};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {1};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {2};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {3};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-2.2,5.5) {NO};
        \node at (-1.5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm, yshift=-5.5cm]
        \tikzmath{\x=15;}
        \fill[color=green!20] (-8,5) rectangle (2,6);
        \node at (-7.5,5.5) {$\x$.};
        
        \node at (-6.5,5.5) {0};
        \node at (-6,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=2.5mm] {};
        
        \node at (-5.5,5.5) {1};
        \node at (-5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-4.5,5.5) {2};
        \node at (-4,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-3.5,5.5) {3};
        \node at (-3,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-2.5,5.5) {4};
        \node at (-2,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
        
        \node at (-1.2,5.5) {NO};
        \node at (-0.5,5.5) [shape=rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=3mm] {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community. Please show us, what you try so far. Where you suck? We are glad to help in such cases but we are not service "do-this-instead-me" ...

Comment: Also, do these boxes (or the whole sheet including the surrounding frame) need to have specific dimensions? I take it that these sheets are meant to be read in via OCR automatically, right? So there might certain requirements as to how large or close to each other those squares should be.

Comment: Thank you for providing your code, but please extend this to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). What you tried already looks quite promising, where exactly do you need help with? I would probably consider creating a custom macro using `\newcommand` or a `\pic` or the like to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just stick some boxes into each other, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{green!20}{%
    \makebox[18em][l]{%
        \makebox[2em][r]{1.}
        \makebox[3em]{A \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{B \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{C \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{D \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
    }%
}

\colorbox{green!20}{%
    \makebox[18em][l]{%
        \makebox[2em][r]{2.}
        \makebox[3em]{A \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{B \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{C \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        \makebox[3em]{D \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
    }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]